# How to ignore a validation / ConstraintValidator in a webservice junit test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-test

I have the following simple webservice that requires a `LocalDate` in future. The annotation is a custom one, as follows:

```
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = DateInFutureValidator.class)
public @interface DateInFuture {
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

public class DateInFutureValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DateInFuture, Temporal> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(DateInFuture constraintAnnotation) { }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Temporal value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        //validation logic
    }
}
```

Question: how can I disable that annotation during a `junit` integration test (that uses a date that will be in the past in a while)?

The spring servlet:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping(path)
    public Rsp post(MyDTO dto) {

    }
}


public class MyDTO {
    @NotNull
    @DateInFuture
    private LocalDate date;
}
```

The ITest:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SpringItest {

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void springItest() {
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post(path)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(requestAsJson)
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to spend some effort in making the json object valid (by using a date that is allays in future) instread of spending time in finding a validation bypass.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible in my specific case (as also relying on different mocked webservice responses, database entries etc).

Comment: how about to rewirte your `DateInFutureValidator` under the test source directory and make the `isValid` always return `true`?

Comment: @holi-java That would be best. But how can I replace the custom validator then?

Comment: classes  in test directory will be loaded first if its full qualifier name same as product classes. did you know what I said?

Comment: This is an absolutely amazing trick. Would you add it as an answer? It works!

Comment: however, it will make you test your actual `DateInFutureValidator` harder since it will load your mocked `DateInFutureValidator` rather than the actual one, :)

Comment: In my case the `DateInFutureValidator` is in a different shared library. The validator itself is tested inside the shared library. Whereas I want to disable the validator only in implementation projects. So that's fine though.

Comment: ooh, in your case use the trick of the `ClassLoader` maybe the best approach, because you can done your work quickly without to know the details of the validation api. My english is bad, did you mind add an answer by yourself?

Comment: Yes I mean that you add your approach as a direct answer (not as a comment). As otherwise I cannot accept it as the solution. PS: your English is good enough!

Comment: hi, sir. I have wrote it down in answer. feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @membersound has already mentioned that the `DateInFutureValidator` is not part of the project, so he needn't test the `DateInFutureValidator` at all. so we can just disable it by use the trick of `ClassLoader` how to load classes.

When there is a class with full qualified name as library class in the test source directory, the `ClassLoader` will load it and ignore the library class.

```
package ${package_name_same_as_library_class};

public class DateInFutureValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DateInFuture, Temporal> {
  @Override
  public void initialize(DateInFuture constraintAnnotation) { }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(Temporal value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

The downside of this approach is it will disable `DateInFutureValidator` globally. but it doesn't matter in this case since it run in integration test only.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with a standalone setup of a MockMvc instance by providing a mock validator which will prevent it from performing any validation.

```
Validator mockValidator = mock(Validator.class);

MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilder.standaloneSetup(myController).setValidator(mockValidator);
```

If you want to do a web application set up of your MockMvc, which is the case with the auto configured MockMvc instance you are currently using then I think you should be able to provide a mock Validator to the whole context by just declairing a @MockBean Validator:

```
@MockBean(name = "mvcValidator")
private Validator mockValidator;
```

Comment: `@MockBean` worked! If it's not possible to just disable one specific annotation, I could live with that.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it!

Comment: Beside, if you load a custom `testing.properties` file you can just add the following property instead of mocking: `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none`